# SQL server datetime order

Tags: sql-server, datetime

I am inserting a single row couple times into SQL server. I just realized that my datetime column captures the time when rows are inserted but they are not in order. For example,

> 2017-11-24 10:21:16.170
>
> 2017-11-24 10:21:35.180
>
> 2017-11-24 10:21:49.170
>
> 2017-11-24 10:22:08.187
>
> 2017-11-24 10:21:24.180
>
> 2017-11-24 10:21:57.170
>
> 2017-11-24 10:21:07.840

Top one being first row and very last one being last row. I expect the first row to be always the the row when the data is inserted for the first time but I see that times are not in order and distributed randomly. Sorry, I am not too familiar with database work and not sure why this appears to be like above.

Comment: When looking at data in a table in a tool or via a SELECT the order is not guaranteed in any way unless you have an ORDER BY clause.  If you were to add a identity column this would reflect the order of insertion and would be the thing to order by.

Comment: What is the question? Also, you should specify your `DateTime` column definition (do you have a default on it?) or the values are generated by the application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A database table is an un-ordered structure. That means there is no order on the way rows are saved on table. Think of it as a heap where we just '*throw*' records without any particular order.

Order comes in place using the `order by` clause on a `SELECT` query.
As long as you don't fetch results using an `order by`, the sequence of rows returned is random.